# Create and save pdf file with electron js

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

I use vuejs with Electron Builder and I really can't generate pdf (invoice type for example), I tried PdfKit, electron-pdf and pdf-creator-node

and each time there is an error, on the internet I can't really find how to do it with electron js, and very often it's node js tutorials that I follow

if you have already managed to implement this or have any links, your help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a file with the name of **vue.config.js** with this code to declare the **pdfkit** library as external to **Electron**

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      externals: ["pdfkit"],
    },
  },
};
```